# TeamCity VCS issue

Tags: java, devops, teamcity, tls1.2, teamcity-9.0

We have an old version of TeamCity 9.0.2 (build 32195) that is running a build with a VCS root that has a fetch URL hosted in Azure DevOps. Without making changes we started seeing the following error when trying to run a build:

[image: TeamCityError]

My suspicions are that TeamCity had been connecting via TLSv1.0 and this is no longer supported as described here:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/deprecating-weak-cryptographic-standards-tls-1-0-and-1-1-in-azure-devops-services/

I have updated the version of the JRE in the Agent's jre folder to version "1.8.0_191" as I understand that this version should connect via TLSv1.2 by default, I have also set the following environment variable to force connections to use TLSv1.2 from Java application:

[image]

After carrying out the above I am still seeing the error and I'm wondering what else can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating the build agent's version of Java *and* the TeamCity service's version of Java to 1.8.0_333 (the latest version) the build could connect to the repository hosted in Azure DevOps.